# how to re-format datetime string in php?

Tags: php, date, sorting, time, date-sorting

I receive a datetime from a plugin. I put it into a variable:

```
$datetime = "20130409163705";
```

That actually translates to *`yyyymmddHHmmss`*.

I would need to display this to the user as a transaction time but it doesn't look proper.

I would like to arrange it to be like *`09/04/2013 16:37:05`* **or** *`09-apr-2013 16:37:05`*.

How do I go about and change the orders of the string?

As for now I could think is to use **substr** to separate the date and time. I'm still not sure on how to add the additional characters and rearrange the date.

Comment: [`date_parse_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) will do what you want.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.date.php ... please

Comment: [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

Comment: I just found this question useful and its 2014, so the people who closed it are talking out of their bottoms.

Comment: Voted to reopen.  While the question shows a specific case, the application to other cases is easy to see.  Found this answer via Google, and it pointed me in the right direction, even though my specific case was different.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

why not use **date()**  just like below,try this

```
$t = strtotime('20130409163705');
echo date('d/m/y H:i:s',$t);
```

and will be output

```
09/04/13 16:37:05
```

Answer (score 47):

For PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$datetime = "20130409163705"; 
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHis", $datetime);
echo $d->format("d/m/Y H:i:s"); // or any you want
```

Result:

```
09/04/2013 16:37:05
```

Answer (score 6):

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2019-05-13"))`

Comment: Can you explain further how that given line relates to the question?

Comment: Please add some explanation for future users to your answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `substr()`, you can easily add the dashes or slashes like this..

```
$datetime = "20130409163705"; 
$yyyy = substr($datetime,0,4);
$mm = substr($datetime,4,6);
$dd = substr($datetime,6,8);
$hh = substr($datetime,8,10);
$MM = substr($datetime,10,12);
$ss = substr($datetime,12,14);
$dt_formatted = $mm."/".$dd."/".$yyyy." ".$hh.":".$MM.":".$ss;
```

You can figure out any further formatting from that point.

Answer (score 2):

You have different options.

**Using date():**

```php
$format = date('d/m/y H:i:s', 1621371929);
echo $format;
```

the output is:

```php
18/05/21 14:05:29
```

**Using date_format():**

```php
$date = date_create(1621371929);
echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y H:i:s');
```

the output is:

```php
18/05/21 14:05:29
```

**Using DateTime::format():**

```php
$date = new DateTime('2021-05-18 14:05:29');
echo $date->format('d/m/y H:i:s');
```

the output is:

```php
18/05/21 14:05:29
```

[This article](https://www.polynique.com/coding/format-datetime-in-php/) gives you an overview of these three methods, and [this one](https://www.polynique.com/coding/how-to-convert-datetime-to-string-in-php/) is **DateTime::format()** in depth.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$datetime = "20130409163705"; 
print_r(date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d H-i-s", $datetime));
```

the output:

```
[year] => 2013
[month] => 4
[day] => 9
[hour] => 16
[minute] => 37
[second] => 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php
$datetime = "20130409163705"; 
$format = "YmdHis";

$date = date_parse_from_format ($format, $datetime);
print_r ($date);
?>
```

You can look at [`date_parse_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) and [the accepted format values.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
https://en.functions-online.com/date.html?command={"format":"l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `date_parse_from_format()` function ...

```php
date_parse_from_format(string $format, string $datetime): array
```

#### Example

```php
<?php
$date = "6.1.2009 13:00+01:00";
print_r(date_parse_from_format("j.n.Y H:iP", $date));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2009
    [month] => 1
    [day] => 6
    [hour] => 13
    [minute] => 0
    [second] => 0
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 1
    [zone_type] => 1
    [zone] => 3600
    [is_dst] => 
)
```

Check [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)..you will get clear idea

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Imagine that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Please take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).