# How to format date in PHP from a string of concatenated numbers?

Tags: php, string, date

I am new to PHP and I am trying to learn more of php date and time but I seem to get stuck with this.

I have this date format:

```
 ddMMyyHHmmss
```

And an example is 120813125055 but I am trying to manipulate the string such that it will give me the format of:

```
 yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss (in the example above, 2013-08-12 12:50:55)
```

I tried to do something like:

```
 date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('120813125055'));
```

But it always gives me a result of 1969-12-31 18:00:00.

I assume that I need to do some string manipulation in PHP for this but I was wondering if there is an easier and more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is in the second response answered here: [how to re-format datetime string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920768/how-to-re-format-datetime-string-in-php)

To summarize (and apply to your example), you could modify the code like this.

```
$datetime = "120813125055"; 
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("dmyHis", $datetime);
echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: This is a good option if the version of `php` you are running on your server is `>= 5.3.0`

Answer (score 4):

Use [date_create_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$ts = date_create_from_format('dmyHis', '120813125055');
$str = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
```

strtotime() only works on EASILY recognizable formats. Your is a ugly mix of garbage, so no surprise that strtotime bails with a boolean `FALSE` for failure, which then gets typecast to an `int 0` when you tried feed it back into `date()`.

And of course, note that your time string is **NOT** y2k compliant. two digit years should never ever be used anymore, except for display purposes.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the reply. I tried your code but I am getting the error: date() expects parameter 2 to be long. Will it matter that date_create_from_format() returns an object and the date() parameter 2 expects only a timestamp format?

Answer (score 0):

You're using your function call and the argument the wrong way around.

In your example, php will try to return you the date for which the time is 'strtotime('120813125055')', and this function returns false (interpreted as 0). So you get returned the date formatted in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' for the Unix epoch.

You will need to get the actual timestamp of your string, so use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken here..

```
I tried to do something like:

date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('120813125055'));
```

You shouldn't use only numbers ( doesnt matter its an integer or a string ), than it will always give you the same thing.

You can use any other valid date and time ( E.G. 6 Jun 2013, 5 may 12...) . Because what    strtotime()    do is detect a valid date and convert it into timestamp.