# how to convert php date format to 3 arguments

Tags: php, datetime

I have this date input :

`$_POST['date']; output is : 2013/10/10`.

Now i need to convert this date format to 3 arguments:

```
$year = '2013'; 

$month = '10';

$date = '10';
```

How do i create this ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920768/how-to-re-format-datetime-string-in-php/15920983#15920983

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) with the [`list`](http://php.net/list) construct, like so:

```
list($year, $month, $date) = explode('/', $_POST['date']);
```

However, this is not a very good idea. I suggest using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class when working with dates and times:

```
$str = "2013/10/10";
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $str);

$month = $dateObj->format('m');
$year  = $dateObj->format('Y');
$date  = $dateObj->format('d');
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d", $_POST['date']);

$year  = $d->format("Y");
$month = $d->format("m");
$day   = $d->format("d");
```

Answer (score 1):

OK try this one It works for me:

**CODING :**

```
   <?PHP
      $your_date =  $_POST['date'];   
      echo "year =".date("Y", strtotime($your_date));
      echo "month =".date("m", strtotime($your_date))";
      echo "day =".date("d", strtotime($your_date));
    ?>
```

Dron

Answer (score 0):

you can use [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) function

```
$date = explode("/", $_POST['date']);
echo $date[0]; //Year
echo $date[1]; //month
echo $date[2]; //Day
```

the explode() function split a string by string and makes an array