# How to Replace url value with variable in php? and get dynamic result in fetch array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, textbox

i want to make number "12345" and date "02-07-2018" dynamic to get its variable value from text box..also i want fetch the result(dynamic) in array.. like mysql_fetch_array(result)..how to achive this ??..any help will be appriated

```
    <?php
    $json = '';
    //url

    $url = 'http://api.website.com/account/12345/date/02-07-2018/apikey/api_key/';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);


    $acc_name = $json['account']['name'];
    $acc_number = $json['account']['number'];

    ?>

    <table width='100%' border=1>

      <thead>
      <tr bgcolor='#00ffcc'>

        <th>account name</th>
        <th>account number</th>

      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

<td> <?php echo $acc_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $acc_number; ?></td>
```

Comment: i tried this  [link]  $url = 'http://api.website.com/account/'.$number.'/date/'.$date.'/apikey/api_key/';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you need for retrieving.

```
$number = $_POST['number'] ;
$date = $_POST['date'] ; /* format if necessary */

$url = "http://api.website.com/account/$number/date/$date/apikey/api_key/";
```

To iterate you can use

```
<?php
foreach( $json['account'] as $value ) {
    $acc_name = $value['name'];
    $acc_number = $value['number'];
?>

<td> <?php echo $acc_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $acc_number; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i tried if(isset($_POST['number'])){ $number = $_POST['number'] ; $url = "http://api.website.com/account/$number/date/02-07-2018/apikey/api_key/"; }else{
 echo "something went wrong, 
}  but not getting result as previous

Comment: you may try printing $url to see what you are requesting. Also you might need to format the date as "02-07-2018" since the text box might have different format like "07/02/2018". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920768/how-to-re-format-datetime-string-in-php

Comment: can u do echo $url; and share what it print ?