# Datetime format as string not object

Tags: php, forms

I am setting up a form, and I need to get the following Sunday from the day the form was sent, I have this as my code in my `mealPrepSend.php` file :

```
$deliveryDate = new DateTime(); 
$deliveryDate->modify('next sunday');
$deliveryDate->format('D d M H:i:s');
```

The form is now giving an error :

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /deli/mealPrepSend.php on line 34
```

I did some reading, and found that its to do with how the output is formatted, any help would be very welcomed!

Many thanks,

Comment: Which line is line 34? Is that even referring to one of the three you have shown above?

Comment: I'm not sure where your error comes from? The code you've given should work just fine as it can be converted to a string just fine. The following returns a string in the format you requested: `$deliveryDate = (new \DateTime('next sunday'))->format('D d M H:i:s');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to re-format datetime string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920768/how-to-re-format-datetime-string-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code snippet instead of the code you are using

```
date('D d M H:i:s',strtotime('next sunday'));
```

You can put the static hour like this

```
echo date('D d M H:i:s',strtotime('next sunday 09:00'));
```

Comment: Thankyou for the fast reply, worked great. How could i set the time to 09:00 instead of 00:00 thankyou!