# How can I swap a character in a string with another character in that same string. (Like swap the positions of a characters in string)

Tags: php

$string = '06/13/2021';

I want to swap it so it becomes '13/06/2021';

I will put it in an if statement. Just need to know what function I use to do this.

I considered this [how to re-format datetime string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920768/how-to-re-format-datetime-string-in-php) but maybe I don't know how to use it. but the issue is that I'm accepting dates from 2 different csv files one has day/month/year format but the other has month/day/year.

I'm using this

```
public function formatDate(string $date): string 
{ 
   $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date); 
   return $date('M j, Y', strtotime($date)); 
}
```

when it goes through the dates from the first file with day/month/year it returns the correct formatted date but when it starts going through the dates from the 2nd format and error occurs in the script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to re-format datetime string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920768/how-to-re-format-datetime-string-in-php)

Comment: I considered this but maybe I don't know how to use it. but the issue is that I'm accepting dates from 2 different csv files one has day/month/year format but the other has month/day/year. I'm using this  public function formatDate(string $date): string
    {
        $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
        return $date('M j, Y', strtotime($date));
    }
}

but when it goes through the dates from the first file with day/month/year it returns the correct formatted date but when it starts going through the dates from the 2nd format and error occurs in the script

Answer (score 0):

For the dates in m/d/y you need to skip the following line

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
```

Form php.net

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Comment: Oh wow. This makes sense. Thanks a lot. I now need to figure out how to separate the dates cause they are all coming into the method through the $date variable. If you have any suggestions as to how I can do this, then ill be grateful

Comment: It depends how you call the function, perahps you can add a 2nd parameter to the function called $format

Comment: Okay, but my function has to recognize when the date format coming from the database table has changed. I have an if statement but its very crude. CreateFromFormat creates the specified format but doesn't recognize the format that is coming into the function. I need to recognize when the date format changes.